# Need Help for Inventory Tracking System with XLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

Sorry for not wording the question better, but I'm a bit confused how to put it.  Please feel free to edit or suggest a better title!

I am making an inventory system for a collection of rental properties.  I track how many items are used per booking in one sheet, and how many are currently in storage in a second sheet.  Normally each property has one storage room, but sometimes multiple properties share the same storage room.

My formula, which works perfectly in cases where a storage room serves only one property, is this:

```
=((XLOOKUP(J$8,'Units Used Per Booking'!$F$3:$R$3,XLOOKUP($E9&$F9,'Units Used Per Booking'!$D$4:$D$199&'Units Used Per Booking'!$E$4:$E$199,'Units Used Per Booking'!$F$4:$R$199)))*(Dashboard!I$2*$D$2))-(XLOOKUP(J$8,'Last Stocktake'!$F$3:$Q$3,XLOOKUP($E9&$F9,'Last Stocktake'!$D$4:$D$199&'Last Stocktake'!$E$4:$E$199,'Last Stocktake'!$F$4:$Q$199)))
```

The formula multiplies the number of each item used per booking (listed in the Units Used Per Booking sheet) by the Number of Bookings Per Month (Dashboard Row 2) by the Desired Months of Supply (D2), then it subtracts the current number of items in the inventory (Last Stocktake).  All for the storage room listed in J8.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to make this work in cases (like London) where multiple properties use the same storage room.

I have a list of Storage Rooms and Properties matched up here (in the Dashboard sheet):
[image]

Here is the sheet where the end formula is.  The code snippet above is in J9:
[image]

The Number of Bookings Per Month sheet:
[image]

The storage room London is associated with the properties London 1 and London 2, that's where I've hit a wall.  I've played around with the Transpose & Unique functions, but I can't figure it out.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be much simpler and used the SUMPRODUCT function.  I ended up paying someone else to figure out this issue, but it worked!  This is what they gave me which worked with the sheet/image below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($K$7:$P$15*($I$7:$I$15=$A7)*($J$7:$J$15=$B7)*($K$1:$P$1=C$6)*$K$3:$P$3)
```

[image]

And the final formula on my sheet:

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Last Stocktake'!$F$4:$AA$178*('Last Stocktake'!$D$4:$D$178=$D14)*('Last Stocktake'!$E$4:$E$178=$E14)*('Last Stocktake'!$F$3:$AA$3=G$13))+SUMPRODUCT('New Purchases'!$F$4:$AA$178*('New Purchases'!$D$4:$D$178=$D14)*('New Purchases'!$E$4:$E$178=$E14)*('New Purchases'!$F$3:$AA$3=G$13))-SUMPRODUCT('Units Used Per Booking'!$F$5:$AA$179*('Units Used Per Booking'!$D$5:$D$179=$D14)*('Units Used Per Booking'!$E$5:$E$179=$E14)*('Units Used Per Booking'!$F$3:$AA$3=G$13)*$F$4:$AA$4)
```